# How to turn off screencast mouse highlighter?

Tags: screencast

I tried the Screencast function, and now this thing wont go away!! :((

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the dismiss button, labelled "Capture",  to the right of the render engine select box.

[image]

Comment: That was the first thing I did. The highlighter still persists!

Comment: Ok so I reverted to an older save file, and now its working normally. Highlighter disappears when I stop capture.

Comment: Lol, just built a new version of blender (from git repo)  and it displays  the behaviour you described.